# 4-bit counter in AHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga, hdl, intel-fpga

I have to write 4 bit counter in AHDL.
I haven't had contact with AHDL before.

The task is:

> Please implement a 4 digit counter (BCD counting) in the circuit
> Cyclone IV EP3CE115F29C7 FPGA being the heart of the commissioning
> system  De2-115 from terasic.

The counter should work with a 1Hz clock to be able to observe the change of states
display in development kit.
The outputs of the seven-segment decoders should be connected to the appropriate
FPGA pins to enable display control.

The final program should allow FPGA programming and observations
counter counting.

I have something similar in VHDL. Can you guys can help me how to rewrite this to altera?
Is there any converter maybe? I saw something like this but only from AHDL to VHDL.
I will be grateful for all the tips.

```
  library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity bcd_counter is
    generic (
    width : integer := 4
    );
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    output : out std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity bcd_counter;

architecture behaviour of bcd_counter is
 signal state : unsigned (2 ** width - 1 downto 0);
begin
output <= std_logic_vector(state);
count : process(clk, reset, enable)
begin
  if(reset = '0') then
    state <= (others=> '0');
  elsif(rising_edge(clk) and enable = '1') then
        state <= state + 1;
  end if;
end process count;
end architecture behaviour;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter_logic is
    generic (
    digits : integer := 4
    );
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    output : out std_logic_vector (4 * digits - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity counter_logic;

architecture behaviour of counter_logic is
 constant digitWidth : integer := 4;
 signal state : std_logic_vector(digitWidth * digits -1 downto 0);
 signal resetLines : std_logic_vector(digits - 1 downto 0);
 signal enableLines : std_logic_vector(digits - 1 downto 0);
 component bcd_counter is
    generic (
    width : integer := 4
    );
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    output : out std_logic_vector(width - 1 downto 0)
    );
 end component;
begin
counters: for i in digits - 1 downto 0 generate
 nthCounter : bcd_counter 
 generic map (width => digitWidth)
 port map (
  clk => clk,
  enable => enableLines(i),
  reset => resetLines(i),
  --przypisanie wyjść liczników do linii
  output => state((i + 1) * digitWidth - 1 downto i * digitWidth)
 );
 resetLines(i) <= (not state(i * digitWidth) and state(i * digitWidth + 1) and state(i * digitWidth + 2) and not state(i * digitWidth + 3)) or reset;
end generate counters;
--TODO: add if generate for case of single digit counter
enableLinesCondition: if digitWidth > 1 generate
lines: for i in digits - 2 downto 0 generate
 enableLines(i + 1) <= not state(i * digitWidth) and state(i * digitWidth + 1) and state(i * digitWidth + 2) and not state(i * digitWidth + 3);
end generate lines;
end generate enableLinesCondition;
enableLines(0) <= '1';
output <= state;
end architecture behaviour;
```

Comment: AHDL is a very old HDL. Are you sure you need to complete your task using AHDL? The task as your describe it does not say that you need to use AHDL. Intel (ie Altera) Quartus understands VHDL.

Comment: Unfortunately I do. Thats the problem. If I can use VHDL I would just finish code that I posted :/

Comment: Ahdl was old and unused 15 years ago.  You are Unlikely to find much on the web. Is this a university project?

Comment: The best reference might be in the \dB\ folder of a quartus project.  Iirc, a lot of the older altera ips are in ahdl and a lot of them get dumped in this temp folder.

Comment: Digital Systems Design and Prototyping Using Field Programmable Logic, Zoran Salcic, Asim Smailagic (auth.) (1st or 2nd), 4  INTRODUCTION TO DESIGN USING AHDL 5 ADVANCED AHDL. [ABEL-HDL Reference Manual](https://www.latticesemi.com/-/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/1D/ABEL-HDLReferenceManual.ashx?document_id=589).

Comment: @Tricky excatly. Prof is old fashioned and told us it would be easier if we use AHDL. But we had only 4/5 lecture of this topic because of pandemic and it's just enoying problem for now.

Comment: @Eazy1908 I highly recommend you get a new professor.  Its not easier for you,  its easier for him.  AHDL can only be simulated in quartus and only as a post synth netlist.  That really is a terrible way to learn.

Comment: [Altera AHDL Language Reference](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/uploads/c/c9/Altera_AHDL_Language_Reference.pdf)